# Grouping plots without groupplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz

Running this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=2in, height=2in,
scale only axis, xmin=0,
xmax=7, xtick={\empty}, ymin=-1, ymax=1.1
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{0 0\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=2in, height=2in,
scale only axis, xmin=0,
xmax=7, xtick={\empty}, ymin=-1, ymax=1.1
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{0 0\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

gives me this image:

[image: example plots]

I would like to join these graphs so they share the same x-axis. But I would like to do this without using `groupplots`, because I will be generating individual .tikz files using `matlab2tikz` and would rather just set it up so I can group them in latex. (`matlab2tikz` does not handle subplots very well.

My desired outcome is (using paint):

[image: Joined plot]

Don't worry about the y-axis, that will be sorted out in MATLAB with the right scaling before exporting.

Edit - Thanks for the comments, yes I am happy to edit the contents of `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}`. As long as the editing isn't as much as copying the second data set into it, then I may as well scrap this idea and go for `groupplots`. Thanks

Thanks

Comment: This might need adoptions to the bounding box of both figures such that x tick labels do not increase the bounding box vertically (compare section "The Picture's Size: Bounding Box and Clipping" in the `pgfplots` manual). Could you edit your question with hints regarding the following question: Is it acceptable to modify the code between `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tizkpicture}` or do you need to keep the `.tikz` files as-is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could comment out or delete an `\end{tikzpicture}` and the following `\begin{tikzpicture}` to get both `axis` environments in the same `tikzpicture`. Then you can give the first axis a `name`, and place the second relative to it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=2in, height=2in,
scale only axis, xmin=0,
xmax=7, xtick={\empty}, ymin=-1, ymax=1.1,
name=first % <-- added
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{0 0\\
};
\end{axis}
%\end{tikzpicture}% <--   commented

%\begin{tikzpicture} % <-- commented
\begin{axis}[%
width=2in, height=2in,
scale only axis, xmin=0,
xmax=7, xtick={\empty}, ymin=-1, ymax=1.1,
at={(first.south west)},anchor=north west % <-- added
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{0 0\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate, that works perfectly. Even using \input. I just edit the relevant areas in each .tikz file. Great!